# Interactive SVG WORLD Maps with mouseover highlights?

Tags: svg

Can anyone direct me to a a world SVG example with mouseover highlights?  I would like to find some nice examples that have a world map with details.

Many thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't have any worldmap example, but I uploaded this javascript mouseover with the state of illinois as an example for you: http://renatorasmussen.com/svgmouse/IL_corn_1972_Detrend_to_2009.svg

These are the files I am using:

```
IL_corn_1972_Detrend_to_2009.svg
map_styles.css
mouse_over_effects.js
```

Answer (score 0):

See Peter Collingridge's work via

- [Is this possible: Zoomable SVG Image Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74409/interactive-world-map-suggestions)

⇢ http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/introduction-svg-scripting-interactive-map

⇢ http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/pan-and-zoom-control

I'm going to try to do this in the new year with a world map, will post back here with more resources if & when I unearth them, a quick read over Peter's intro tutorial says it's a “very popular” use for SVGs.